# codeigniter project not loading in localhost using wampserver

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, wamp

Sorry, but I'm forgetting the basics here.

I have my codeigniter project and I set it up in localhost using wamp.

database settings are correctly setup.

Here are my settings for codeigniter;

in `application/config`

```
switch(ENVIRONMENT) {
    case 'development' :    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/'; break;
    case 'testing':         $config['base_url'] = 'http://160.16.204.159/'; break;
    case 'production':      $config['base_url'] = 'http://system.bnb-brams.com/'; break;
}
```

in `application/public/index.php`

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
```

Then in my apache's `httpd.conf` this is the setting;

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80

and

ServerName localhost:80
```

All services are running on wamp.

when I load it on the chrome browser, typing in `http://localhost:8080/`, it says;

```
This site can’t be reached

localhost refused to connect.
      Did you mean http://localhost-8080.com/?
      Search Google for localhost 8080
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I totally forgot how to setup things together in codeigniter and wamp, I need help.

Answer (score 0):

Your apache seems not being listening at 8080 port, just 80.

Add

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
```

Or change it in the first listen line.

Comment: Would be simpler to just remove the port number from the codeigniter config line!

Comment: Depending on local configuration. I supossed that he is in the same situation than me, i've got IIS listening on 80 port and apache with WAMP at port 8080

Answer (score 0):

Apache is listening on port 80 and not port 8080 as you show us from your `httpd.conf`

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
```

So change this line to use port 80 and not port 8080. In fact if its on port 80 you do not need to use the port on this line as 80 is always the default for a web server.

```
case 'development' :    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/'; break;
```